# How to join table and count the number of specify column in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

now i try to get the count number of specific column in join table which using sqlalchemy with postgresql, and this is my table that i have join.

[image]

The column that i want to count is `Nodes.status` which have three value consist of 1, 2 and 3.
And i want to know how many of each status of each customer is like the example below.

```
[customer_name, number_of_status_1, number_of_status_2, number_of_status_3]
```

So how can i do that, and this is how i join the table.

```
db.session.query(Customers, Sites, Nodes).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import func

...

sites = db.session.query(Sites.customer_id.label('site_customer_id'),
func.count(Nodes.id).filter(Nodes.status == 1).label('number_of_status_1'),
func.count(Nodes.id).filter(Nodes.status == 2).label('number_of_status_2'),
func.count(Nodes.id).filter(Nodes.status == 3).label('number_of_status_3')
 ).outerjoin(Nodes).group_by(Sites.id).subquery()


query = db.session.query(Customers.name,
func.sum(sites.c.number_of_status_1),
func.sum(sites.c.number_of_status_2),
func.sum(sites.c.number_of_status_2)
).join(sites, sites.c.site_customer_id == Customers.id).group_by(Customers.id)

for row in query.all():
    print(row)
```